# Simplest way to integrate an offboard camera with iDevice/Android?

Tags: camera, core-bluetooth

I'd like to avoid any dead-end efforts here, so I'll throw this out to the crowd.

I need to take low-resolution snapshots using an offboard camera. The camera will be placed under a plastic dome to provide fish-eye images of the sky, so I can calculate cloud coverage. To do so, you normally have to put the camera on the top of a pole. On-demand photos is all that's need, no video or timers or anything like that.

XGA resolution is fine, and I could go lower if need be. The images then need to be sent to a mobile device, with the first target being the iDevice line. Support for Android is definitely nice.

I'm perfectly happy using a cable for this, but I suspect BT is the way to go here? Any and all advice happily accepted - especially if you know of a device that already works in this fashion.

Comment: Wi-Fi could be a solution, even if it more energyvore... Android doesn't (yet ?) really support BLE.

Comment: Ok, is there a lightweight protocol for doing this under WiFi? An entire networking stack would definitely not be worth it.